# Can you remove boolean constants from a propositional formula in polynomial time?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

By boolean constants, I mean the constants true and false where A(true) = 1 and A(false) = 0 for any assignment A. For any arbitrary formula F, is it possible to remove all instances of true and false (boolean constants) from the formula in polynomial time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some proposition $P$. Now just replace every instance of "true" with $P\lor \lnot P$ and replace every instance of "false" with $P\land \lnot P$. This can be carried out in linear time in the length of the formula.

If we call the old formula $\varphi$ and the new formula $\varphi'$, this transformation has the additional property that for any assignment $A$, $A(\varphi) = A(\varphi')$. I assume that you wanted this property, although you didn't specify it in your question.